# Pointers problem - Finding odd numbers and storing them in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, pointers

I was given the function, and I added this bit of code to go through the numbers in the array, then I had another variable to count the number of odd numbers, to put in a second array

```
int CopySelected(const int array[], int size, int odd_numbers[])
{
    int oddCounter = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
     {
         if (array[i]%2 != 0)
         odd_numbers[++oddCounter] = array[i];
     }
    return oddCounter;
    
}
```

The code passed for mistakes, but it failed.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to learn post and pre increment operators differences.

Comment: `odd_numbers[++oddCounter] = array[i];` should be `odd_numbers[oddCounter++] = array[i];`. Better still don't use the increment operators in sub-expressions, they are inherently confusing.

Answer (score 5):

This increases `oddCounter` *before* assigning the element:

```cpp
odd_numbers[++oddCounter] = array[i];
```

It should be:

```cpp
odd_numbers[oddCounter++] = array[i];
```

or

```cpp
odd_numbers[oddCounter] = array[i];
++oddCounter;
```

Your function could also be simplified by using the standard algorithm [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

std::size_t CopySelected(const int array[], std::size_t size, int odd_numbers[]) {
    return std::copy_if(array, array + size, odd_numbers,
                        [&](int value) -> bool { return value % 2; }) -
           odd_numbers;
}
```

You could however simplify it further by using `std::vector<int>`s instead of arrays:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> CopySelected(const std::vector<int>& array) {
    std::vector<int> odd_numbers;
    std::copy_if(array.begin(), array.end(), std::back_inserter(odd_numbers),
                 [&](int value) -> bool { return value % 2; });
    return odd_numbers;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    std::vector<int> odd = CopySelected(arr);
    for (int value : odd) {
        std::cout << value << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: the first step just solved the problem. changing odd_numbers[++oddCounter] = array[i]; to odd_numbers[oddCounter++] = array[i];.

Comment: @Sterrock Yes, that's correct. Using standard algorithms when possible is however usually preferred since it makes it clear to a future reader of the code what's going on.

Comment: @Sterrock if you had put the second and third steps first you wouldnt have made the mistake that step one fixes. The answer not only tells you how to fix it but how to never make that mistake again

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're learning C++ from a somewhat outdated source. Here is an example that is using current C++.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges> //C++20 only

bool is_odd(const int value)
{
    return (value % 2) == 1;
}

int main()
{
    // In C++ do NOT use "C" style arrays, use std::vector which is resizable (or std::array fixed size)
    std::vector<int> values{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    std::vector<int> odd_values;

    // range based for loops cannot go out of bound
    // auto& means do NOT copy the values in the vector
    // const promises not to change any of the values 
    // (we're reading them only)
    for (const auto& value : values)
    {
        // use a predicate for readability
        if (is_odd(value))
        {
            odd_values.push_back(value);
        }
    }

    // And output the odd numbers
    for(const auto& value : odd_values)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
    // Not in C++20 you can also do this
    // no copy of values is needed you just
    // iterate over the odd values only
    for(const auto & value : values | std::views::filter(is_odd))
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```